# How to run multiple test cases sequentially in NUnit Console Runner

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, nunit

I'm trying to run nunit3 exe through Jenkins but after building the project, it runs all available test cases parallely. They should run sequetially.

I tried where clause in nunit but how it will help with multiple categories?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to run nunit3 exe through Jenkins but after building the project, it runs all available test cases parallely.

This happens if you are using the [[Parallelizable](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallelizable-Attribute)] attribute. By default, no parallel execution takes place.